# How to make Thread constructor take values from LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, distributed-computing

I am working on an assignment for a Distributed Systems module which involves *simulating a push gossiping protocol with multiple threads* in Java.

My program takes a .txt file in adjacency list format ("node: neighbour1, neighbour2, etc."):

```
1:2,4,6
2:1,3,4,5
.
.
.
```

And creates a LinkedHashMap with K = node, V = String(of all neighbors), which looks like:

```
{1=2,4,6, 2=1,3,4,5 ...}
```

To be more specific the LinkedHashMap has K = String, V = String.

From this map I can create a List with nodes with the Map method map.keySet(), and a separate list with neighbors with the map.values() method. I can also create an Array of type String, or String[] of neighbours.

Each node can only communicate with its neighbors which are defined as values in the LinkedHashMap.

**Gossip (push) protocol:**
Assume one node has the information initially. The informed node sends the info to a randomly selected neighbor, drawn from it's set of neighbors (with replacement). 
The initial node has to send the information via a separate interconnect thread. When the neighbor receives the information from the interconnect, it does the same thing as the initial node. In other words, it randomly selects a neighbor from its own set of neighbors and sends the info further via the interconnect. Eventually, everyone has the information and the protocol terminates.

**My problem is the following:** 
Given the LinkedHashMap, how can I instantiate a node on a key basis such that each node knows who is it neighbors? More directly, how can the constructor for the Node Thread take a specific Key with a specific Value from the LinkedHashMap?

When I try something like this, it gives me the entire list of neighbors, and not those specific to the node.

```
public Node extends Thread {
    public Node(Integer ID, List<String> neighbors){
    }
}
```

*Addition:**

I was asked to clarify what "communicate" implies. Please see this video from Coursera:

https://www.coursera.org/learn/cloud-computing/lecture/5AOex/1-2-the-gossip-protocol

Comment: It's not clear what neighbouring mechanism emulates here, and what "communicate" means. Is this emulating established connections?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will now clarify more.

Comment: Here is a description of the protocol:

Assume only one node has the information initially. The informed node sends the info to a randomly selected neighbour, drawn from it's set of neighbours (with replacement). The node has to send the information via the interconnect.
When the neighbour receives the information, it does the same thing as the initial Node. The thread may not start until it has the information. Once it gets the information it randomly selects a neighbour. Clearly, the topology of the graph determines how quickly it will take before the protocol terminates.

Comment: That explanation (or at least the note that it's a gossip protocol) should be added to the question itself. As for design, that's a problem where you should design for yourself who "owns the phone book". Does sender know who he sends to? Then he has the book. Does sender only explaim into the Aether, and someone might "overhear"? Then the interconnect thread has the book, he acts as an Aether, receives the message and the sender in a "bundle", then based on the sender decides who can overhear the message.

Comment: The sender knows that he will send to one of his neighbors. However, it is random which one of his neighbors he sends to in a given round.

Comment: Then sender should know who is near him, and message should include a recipient in it. Then interconnect distributes message to recipient. (After all this excange I still don't get what is the problem you're asking here).

Comment: My problem is code oriented. How can I instantiate the node such that it knows who is its neighbors? When I try, each node has the entire set of all neighbors rather than the ones specific to his key.

Comment: You have to give the node only what he should know. Considering you have a map of `Map<Id, Set<Id>>`, your node constructor is `Node(Id, Set<Id>)`, so it represents a single entry in the map. You never give it the map itself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I have now edited the question further. I am not sure how to write the constructor that way given that my map is LinkedHashMap<String,String> initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a key-value pair from a `Map` to a constructor or a method, you can do this:

```
public Node extends Thread {
    public Node(Map.Entry<String, String> entry) {
        String id = entry.getKey();
        String neighbors = entry.getValue();

        // ...
    }
}
```

And then you can call it the way you want.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Node node = new Node(entry);
}
```

[Map.entrySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet())

[Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)

Comment: Thank you! This finally fixed the issue such that each node has a finite set of connecting nodes.

Comment: I would take this further and split map value so that neighbors are a first-class thing rather than malleable thing: `entry.getValue().split(",")`.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking into how to do now :)

Comment: Also, many thanks for your comments earlier. I understand now why you used the Set<Id> parameter in your constructor explanation.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov , That also makes sense, if this was my problem I wouldn't consider using a string to represent list of elements in this way.

Comment: @M.S. Yeah, I agree about the representation. Once I have the protocol implemented I will clean up the code so that the LinkedHashMap takes the correct types for K and V.